# WCF : Service receiving "null" string after being sent a full string

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing a very simple WCF Example, but I am dismally failing into retrieving, in server side, the string value I am sending from client side. My code is very basic though. If anyone could lead me to the tracks where to look at to fix this I would be very grateful (And please forgive my limited WCF knowledge)

**EDIT :** Funny Part is that I am able to retrieve a return value in client back from server !
 (see modified code below)

**Client code :**

```
    public void SendData()
    {
        string rogerback = proxy.SendData("String To Be Delivered");
        Console.Writeline(rogerback); //<--Prints "PICKABOO" 
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "IServiceOrder")]
    public interface IServiceOrder
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IServiceOrder/SendData")]            
        string SendData(string data);
    }
```

**Server Code :**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceOrder
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SendData(string data);        
}

public class ServiceOrder : IServiceOrder
{     
    public string SendData(string value)
    {

        if (value== null) Console.WriteLine("value IS NULL"); //<--Always the case when I execute Client code SendData()
        return "PICKABOO";
        //return value <-- returns null
        doSomething(value);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to put breakpoints on each side as low as you can to the servicemodel code to ensure you are sending what you expect? Also put one on the receive side, in case your code is not exactly as you posted it.

Comment: @wal : I have put a breakpoint on client side at "proxy.SendData("String To Be Delivered");" and it is hit without any exception nor issue. On the server side, the "value IS NULL" is thrown whenever I call the client code, and of that I am sure, as I can see this exception thrown on the server side monitoring

Comment: LOL... That's not an option as my solution is pretty heavy and this code is just a tiny part of it. Isolating it in a separate solution/project would be a bit costly at the moment

Comment: Like the answer below, your proxy class is probably fishy. You can construct your own client proxy pretty easily which would be worth trying to eliminate that being the issue.

Comment: That is *very* strange however implies that proxy is the likely cause. Can you decompile or post the code generated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5198/discussion-between-mika-jacobi-and-wal)

Answer (score 2):

though I dont know what is your issue may be something wrong with your generate code
Here is full working example for sending a string from client and then receiving it from server.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace MySpace
{

  [DataContract]
  public class Data
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string MyString;

  }
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    Data Method(Data dd);
  }

  public class Service : IService
  {
    public Data Method(Data dd)
    {
      dd.MyString = dd.MyString + " String from Server.";
      return dd;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string Url = "http://localhost:8000/";
      Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, Url);
      host.Open();
      ChannelFactory<IService> fac = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding);
      fac.Open();
      IService proxy = fac.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(Url));
      Data d = new Data();
      d.MyString = "String from client.";
      d = proxy.Method(d);
      fac.Close();
      host.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("Result after calling \n " + d.MyString);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Update: ran code without DataContract by just passing string it works fab

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace MySpace
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string Method(string dd);
  }

  public class Service : IService
  {
    public string Method(string dd)
    {
      dd  =dd+ " String from Server.";
      return dd;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string Url = "http://localhost:8000/";
      Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, Url);
      host.Open();
      ChannelFactory<IService> fac = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding);
      fac.Open();
      IService proxy = fac.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(Url));


      string d = proxy.Method("String from client.");
      fac.Close();
      host.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("Result after calling \n " + d);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Update 3 I still believe there was something wrong with your generated code/proxies as here is test with different interfaces on client/server ( Any way you can ignore it, if your problem is already solved :)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace MyClient
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string Method(string dd);
  }
}

namespace MyServer
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string Method(string dd);
  }
}

namespace MySpace
{  
  public class Service :MyServer.IService
  {
    public string Method(string dd)
    {
      dd  =dd+ " String from Server.";
      return dd;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string Url = "http://localhost:8000/";
      Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyServer.IService), binding, Url);
      host.AddDefaultEndpoints();
      host.Open();

      ChannelFactory<MyClient.IService> fac = new ChannelFactory<MyClient.IService>(binding);
      fac.Open();
      MyClient.IService proxy = fac.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(Url));


      string d = proxy.Method("String from client.");
      fac.Close();
      host.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("Result after calling \n " + d);

      Console.ReadLine();

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "MyCustomClass" is never used in your code. Ill give my code a double check using the rest o yours

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a misconception from my side, concerning how WCF interfaces work.

As you can see in my code, ***interface "IServiceOrder" is defined twice***. *Both on Client AND server side*.
Surjit Samra's code contained only one definition for the interface, and [Ralf's Sudelbücher's example](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx) defined it only once in "WCFSimple.Contract" namespace. 
The fact that the interface was defined twice was what caused the service to "fail" in a very peculiar way. 
If somebody could give a thorough explanation on why this double interface definition causes this behaviour, that would be good.

Basically, I've chosen to do so because I wanted my client to be totally agnostic of the server implementation. But I was mislead, as both client and server need to see AND access a ***single*** interface (i.e contract) definition. I guess that's how it works.

Comment: A brief explanation is that in WCF, the C# interface is a **means** to an **end**: it exists primarily to define the structure of the _messages_ to be exchanged between the client and the service. WCF provides the attributes to mark service operations (methods) and data contracts (types) that define the message. The client interface was telling WCF how to format the [soap message](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap-b) to be sent to the service. The service interface defined how to translate the received soap message into a call of the correct service method with the necessary parameter values.

Comment: @SixtoSaez : Fair Enough. But where was the string value sent by client lost ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added a service reference, delete that service reference completely. add a service reference newly to your client application and run the application.

The reason for the old reference name is, whenever we create a web service reference, a reference file will be created. Eventhough we update/ configure the web service the old reference name will be sustained in the reference file. When you completely delete and add the service reference a new reference file will be created, there after the values will not be null. This is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you forgot to include the attribute [DataMember]
I suggest that you use proper class object to serve as your parameter.
In that way it represented in a well formed object.